# What is the correct format for this time data to use in a python script?

Tags: python

"01.08.2017 00:00:00.000"

What is the correct way to define this data set in a python script is it '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'

Thanks for your help. Still learning

Comment: Did you try that format, and did it produce the correct results?

Comment: Yes i tried but says it does not match the data set

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "does not match the data set".  Instead of making us guess what you're doing, please show us your code and the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format that you have specified is like this:

```
In : datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
Out: '19.10.2017 20:04:55.947244'
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) you can find a list of all allowed directives.

Comment: Nice answer, would add a source so that he could figure it out himself, such as http://strftime.org/